# GitLab Backup no space left on device

Tags: gitlab, backup, devops, admin

I have to migrate our old GitLab server to another one. Therefore I tried to create a backup using the following command:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=uploads,artifacts,builds
```

During backing up the repositores I get the following error:

```
Error No space left on device
rake aborted!
Backup::Error: Backup operation failed: 
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

Does someone know a way to create a backup if the server doesn't have enough space left? Is there a way to exclude specific repositories for a backup so I could split it into many backups?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 16.1 there is a solution to [exlude repositories from rake backup task](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18287). You can do this with the parameter `SKIP_REPOSITORIES_PATHS`:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=uploads,artifacts,builds SKIP_REPOSITORIES_PATHS=toolbox/gitlab-smoke-tests
```

The repository path is the full path to the repository. If you have a group with the name `toolbox` and a project with the Name `GitLab Smoke Tests` with the path `gitlab-smoke-tests`, the full repository path will be `toolbox/gitlab-smoke-tests`. In the most cases you can go to the project overview page of your repository and copy the last part of the url to get the full path.

There is also a [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/backup_restore/backup_gitlab.html#back-up-specific-repositories) about this feature with a description.